# Creating a function inside a function inside a class

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-class

Let's say I have some class with some function inside:

```
var someClass = class someClass() {
  constructor() {}

  someFunction(someObj)
  {
    function anotherFunction() {
      return JSON.stringify(someObj, null, 2);
    }

    return someObj;
  }
}
```

In this context, I could call `someClass.someFunction(someObj)`, and it would return `[object Object]`. Upon trying to call `someClass.someFunction(someObj).anotherFunction()`, it comes up with a `TypeError: someClass.someFunction(...).anotherFunction is not a function`.

How could I circumvent this? I tried creating a prototype like `someClass.prototype.someFunction.anotherFunction = function() {...}`, but that doesn't work.

Many Thanks in advance,
@Medallyon.

Comment: Wouldn't you just need to `return {anotherFunction};` instead of `return someObj;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a function (`anotherFunction`) and never doing anything with it. The JavaScript engine probably optimizes it away entirely.

If you want it to be accessible outside `someFunction`, you need to do something to make it accessible outside `someFunction`. You might return it. Or return an object that has it as a property. Or add it as a property to `someObj` (though that would be unusual).

So for instance, here we return a new object with both the function and the original `someObj` on it (because you were returning that for some reason):

```js
var someClass = class someClass {
  constructor() {}

  someFunction(someObj) {
    function anotherFunction() {
      return JSON.stringify(someObj, null, 2);
    }

    return {
      someObj, anotherFunction
    };
  }
};

var sc = new someClass();
var o = sc.someFunction({
  foo: "bar"
});
console.log(o.anotherFunction());
```

---

Side notes:

- Your `someClass` declaration is incorrect; you shouldn't have `()` after in `var someClass = class someClass() {`.
- The `var someClass =` part of that is pointless if the variable name and class name are the same. If they're different, at least use `let` so the hoisting is the same for the variable as it would be for the class (e.g., it's only half-hoisted).
- The *overwhelming* convention in JavaScript is for constructor functions to start with a capital letter; so `SomeClass`, not `someClass`. While you can use any convention in your own code you like, I would strongly recommend using this one, it helps people reading your code. At the very least, follow it when asking questions.

Comment: How would I access `someObj` from `o` in this scenario? I tried doing `o.someObj`, but that seems to produce a very weird object: http://i.imgur.com/DTyKz3e.png

Comment: Never mind, I found out that the `someObj` object that I passed to `anotherFunction()` is like that already.

Answer (score 1):

`someClass.someFunction(...).anotherFunction` does *not*  refer to an "inner" function of `someFunction`; instead, it refers to the function `anotherFunction` on the object that is returned by `someFunction`. Thus you need to return some object that has `anotherFunction` as a member function for this to work.

Example:

```
var someClass = class someClass() {
  constructor() {}

  someFunction(someObj)
  {
    function anotherFunction() {
      return JSON.stringify(someObj, null, 2);
    }

    // note the difference here
    return {
      // anotherFunction is a member function of the return object
      anotherFunction: anotherFunction,
    };
  }
}
```